# Why no double vav in the acrostic?

Tags: yom-kippur, aleph-bet-letters, musaf

In Musaf of Yom Kippur, we say a prayer (page 574 in the Artscroll Machzor) which begins “umerov avoneinu ein lanu:” and then it goes through a double acrostic of things we no longer have, beginning with ishim and asham (aleph). Then badim and b’lulot (bet) etc.

But when it gets to vav, the two options are vidui and par chatat! Why no double Vav? I hesitate to think that the composer couldn't find another word or phrase to fit in. I can see that those two ideas are related but for every other letter, two words/phrases which begin with the same letter are listed. Why would it be different for this one letter?

Comment: Ever notice what the vav is in the ashamnus? Vihirshanu. Vav words are not so easy to come by. Look in the vav section of tehilim 119.

Comment: הועד ותיקות לח"י עולמין

Comment: Re "for every other letter, two words/phrases which begin with the same letter are listed": I don't have it before me but seem to recall that for פ the poem uses לא פרכת ולא כפרת, in which case ו isn't the only one without two words beginning with it in its line.

Comment: @msh210 yes, I saw that afterwards. I'm not sure if those two are so poetically or thematically closely related that it provides an exception.

Comment: @user6591 There are enough other prayers which have vav words and the other lettered words are often arcane. I can't believe that a vav word couldn't have been found. IIRC the samech words in the Al Chet are "sins" but that isn't because there are no chataim starting with samech.

Comment: @Danno whether or not the words exist doesn't seem to matter. Nobody bothers to use them. See also Eicha 4:6 Vayigdal. The real question would be why not use any word with a vav hachibur like all these other instances. One thing that did occur to me though. Perhaps this paytan had a speach impediment like the tanna in the begining of the sixth chapter of Peah who says הבקר instead of הפקר. We see there a peh making a v sound.

Comment: @user6591 at least the v sound would have made some modicum of sense.  I would have prefered vi'ud ha'am, vered (mar'eh kohen), vatik, or some word (as other prayers use) that has a vav later in the word (such as todi'ah).